# What are the correct types to map variables using Mapbox in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

After taking a look to [mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=sem%7Cgoogle%7Cbrand%7Cchko-googlesearch-pr01-dynamicsearchcampaign-nb.broad-all-landingpage-search&utm_term=brand&utm_content=chko-googlesearch-pr01-dynamicsearchcampaign-nb.broad-all-landingpage-search&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImYqUwa3g5wIV1_ZRCh2rAg_2EAAYASAAEgI_SPD_BwE), I wrote this component

```
import React from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import "./Map.css";

mapboxgl.accessToken = "...";

type Props = {
  longitude: number;
  latitude: number;
};

class Map extends React.Component<Props> {
  private mapContainer: any;
  private map: any;

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      center: [this.props.longitude, this.props.latitude],
      style: "....",
      zoom: 13
    });
  }
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div
        ref={(el): void => {
          this.mapContainer = el;
        }}
        className="mapContainer"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

This code works correctly, however, in my real project, we are using TypeScript. I don't want to use `any` for `mapContainer` and `map`.

I have imported `"@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.7.0",` into my project, but I cannot figure out what type I have to use here.

My tries until now:

- `private map:mapboxgl.Map`. It seems to be correct, but then it complais because it is not initialized on the constructor. According to mapbox documentation it has to be initialize on `componentDidMount`. I can type the variable with `mapboxgl.Map | null`. But then i have to check constally to not be null, to remove
  some annoying warnings.
- `private mapContainer = React.userRef<HtmlElement>(null);`. But then, when i try to initialize the map, it says Type `'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | HTMLElement'.`

Any ideas?

Comment: For `this.map` use: `this.map: Map`, with the import `import { Map } from "@types/mapbox-gl"` for the mapContainer you could try to use `HtmlElement` instead of an `HtmlDivElement`

Comment: `HtmlElement` seems to be correct, but it complains when I try to initialize the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based upon your code, the following works. First, you need to import the `Map` type which get's exported from `mapbox-gl`:

```js
import mapbox-gl, { Map } from "mapbox-gl";
```

Which later can be used as a type for the map inside your component:

```js
private map: Map | undefined; // | undefined is needed here otherwise Typescript will complain about a missing initialiser inside the constructor.
```

Now comes the tricky part, container is defined as:

```js
container: string | HTMLElement
```

inside the MapboxOptions type definition. Therefore we have to workaround it a little bit:

```js
class SampleMap extends React.Component<Props> {
  private mapContainer: HTMLElement | null | undefined = undefined;
  private map: Map | undefined;

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container:
        this.mapContainer === undefined || this.mapContainer === null
          ? "" // or pass in some other HTMLElement which is definitely defined or similar ...
          : this.mapContainer,
      ... // abbreviated
    });
  }
  render(): JSX.Element {
    ... // abbreviated
  }
}
```

There a check if the `mapContainer` is defined and not null and pass in the `mapContainer` otherwise a `string` or maybe you could pass in some other `HTMLElement` which you know is 100% defined. E.g. `document#root`.

Complete code can be found here: [on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-architecture-ish1r)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works as expected. But I have a little concern. In `componentDidMount` the map it's initialized. However, using `this.map` in `componentDidUpdate` shows a complain because `is posible undefined`. To remove the warning i have to check `this.map !== undefined`. But this should not be necesary, due `componentDidUpdate` is always exectued after didMount.